# Access violation 0xc0000005 in a custom TabControl in Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor, maui, access-violation

Recently I've been getting into Blazor and I've mostly used ready components from Telerik and Radzen. However in order to properly learn all that good stuff I want to create custom components and simple ones are going well.

However now I needed to code a TabControl component and I have found [this](https://blazor-university.com/templating-components-with-renderfragements/creating-a-tabcontrol/) guide and followed closely. My problem now is that Visual Studio stops debugging and closes the app when I'm navigating to the page containing my CustomTabControl. This is what VS tells me:

> The program '[4428] FactoryVisual.exe' has exited with code 3221225477 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.

Now my problem isn't understanding what that means, it's where I have caused this in my code. I am still fairly new to coding so I hope this isn't a waste-of-timey issue. Here it is with uninteresting bits cut out, it's pretty much the same as the guide's code-example logically (or so I hope/believe):

`MachineTypeEditView.razor`

```
<CustomTabControl>
    <CustomTab Name="Tab1">
        This is test-content.<br/>
        <button>Testbutton1</button>
    </CustomTab>
    <CustomTab Name="Tab2">
        This is test-content.<br />
        <button>Testbutton2</button>
    </CustomTab>
</CustomTabControl>
```

`CustomTabControl.razor`

```
<div style="width: @Width ; heigth: @Height ;">
    <CascadingValue Value="this">
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            @foreach (var tab in Tabs)
            {
                <CustomTabButton Text="@tab.Name" Click="@(() => SwapTab(tab))" />
            }
        </div>
        @ChildComponent
    </CascadingValue>
</div>


@code
{
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment<CustomTab>? ChildComponent { get; set; }

    public CustomTab ActiveTab { get; set; } = new();

    public List<CustomTab> Tabs = new();

    internal void AddPage(CustomTab newTab)
    {
        Tabs.Add(newTab);

        if (Tabs.Count == 1)
        {
            ActiveTab = Tabs.First();
        }

        StateHasChanged();
    }

    private string GetButtonClass(CustomTab tab)
    {
        // todo
        return "test";
    }

    private void SwapTab(CustomTab tab)
    {
        ActiveTab = tab;
    }
}
```

`CustomTab.razor`

```
@if (ParentControl.ActiveTab == this)
{
    @ChildContent
}

@code
{
    [Parameter]
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [CascadingParameter]
    private CustomTabControl ParentControl { get; set; } = new();

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        ParentCheck();

        base.OnInitialized();
    }

    private void ParentCheck()
    {
        if (ParentControl == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(ParentControl), "CustomTab must exist within a CustomTabControl.");
        }

        TellParent();
    }

    private void TellParent()
    {
        ParentControl.AddPage(this);
    }
}
```

I did not include the CustomTabButton since I've tested the code without and the issue still came up. Originally I have used this component in a .MAUI Blazor app, but that told me absolutely nothing and just couldn't load the page. Then I have used it in a Blazor Server App to get the console output from above.

Let me know if you need more code-spamming to give me a hint.

Comment: This kind of error can basically only happen in unmanaged code. So there's either a bug in a library you're using or you use P/Invoke somewhere incorrectly. Do you have any unmanaged code/libraries in your project?

Comment: I don't entirely understand what you mean with "unmanaged". The MAUI Project was pretty much fresh so there wasn't anything other than a one or two finished components and the code you see in there. I added no kind of dependencies. The Blazor Server App also works fully until I go to my test page. Also created another fresh Blazor Projekt and the same issue occurs.

Comment: I don't have experience with blazor, but that is very weird. I did make the experience that for some reason the latest .NET runtime versions are somewhat more sensitive to buffer overruns, but the behavior you describe would really be a surprisingly obvious bug. Maybe some component is corrupted, so you might want to reinstall the .NET runtime.

Comment: I will give that a try soon and report back.

Comment: @PMF - The problem was a circular reference.  In  `CustomTabControl`, `public CustomTab ActiveTab { get; set; } = new();` creates a new `CustomTab`, which then on  this line `private CustomTabControl ParentControl { get; set; } = new();` creates a new `CustomTabControl` and round and round. and round....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is trying to new up components and then using them.  It took quite a lot of commenting and refactoring to get your code to stop crashing!

I've refactored the code somewhat to:

1. Get rid of those problems and to stop cascading `CustomTabControl` [one of my pet hates].
2. Use some more modern and advanced sub-component registration techniques.  You can see this technique used in `QuickGrid`.

Here's `CustomTabControl`.  It now just cascades the registration `Action`.

```cs
<div class="container-fluid">
    <CascadingValue Value="RegisterTab">
        <nav class="nav nav-pills nav-fill">
            @foreach (var tab in Tabs)
            {
                <a class="@this.GetButtonClass(tab)" @onclick="@(() => SwapTab(tab))">@tab.Name</a>
            }
        </nav>
        @if (_firstRender)
        {
            @*this renders the actual custom Tabs so thay can register - we only do it on the first render*@
            @ChildContent
        }
        else
        {
            @*After the first render we just render the ChildContent in the active tab*@
            @ActiveTab?.ChildContent
        }
    </CascadingValue>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }

    private CustomTab? ActiveTab { get; set; }
    private List<CustomTab> Tabs = new();
    private bool _firstRender = true;

    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        // This uses a bit of magic where we use the double render 
        // built into CompomnentBase's lifecycle process to register the sub-components on the first yield 
        // provided by Task.Delay 
        await Task.Delay(1);
        _firstRender = false;
    }

    private void RegisterTab(CustomTab newTab)
    {
        // check if the tab is already registered
        if (Tabs.Any(item => item == newTab))
            return;

        Tabs.Add(newTab);

        // Set the first tab as the active tab
        if (Tabs.Count == 1)
            SwapTab(Tabs.First());

        StateHasChanged();
    }

    private string GetButtonClass(CustomTab tab)
        => tab == ActiveTab ? "nav-link active" : "nav-link";

    private void SwapTab(CustomTab tab)
        => ActiveTab = tab;
}
```

`CustomTab` is now a class.  It's content is `ChildContent` which we can access from `CustomTabControl`.

```cs
public class CustomTab : ComponentBase
{
    [Parameter] public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [CascadingParameter] private Action<CustomTab>? Register { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        if (Register == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("No Registation Action cascaded.");

        this.Register.Invoke(this);
    }
}
```

And finally Index.razor

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<CustomTabControl>
    <CustomTab Name="Content 1">
        <div class="alert alert-danger m-2">
            This is Content 1.<br />
            <button class="btn btn-danger">Stop</button>
        </div>
    </CustomTab>
    <CustomTab Name="Content 2">
        <div class="alert alert-success m-2">
            This is Content 2.<br />
            <button class="btn btn-success">Start</button>
        </div>
    </CustomTab>
</CustomTabControl>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, your example works well. As I see it ill have a bit of research to do now. Thanks again!

Comment: The original concept came from Steve Sanderson.  This is an adaption of that.  You can see the quick grid stuff here - https://aspnet.github.io/quickgridsamples/.

Comment: Well but you pointed me in the right direction. I have done a little research and I think I understand your code example now. However while doing it like that works in my Blazor Server Projekt, using the same code in my .MAUI Blazor App makes me face another problem: The CustomTab doesn't get detected as a component in the razor markup. I am wondering, is this solution exclusive to pure Blazor Applications? Shouldn't it also work in a hybrid MAUI Blazor App?

Comment: It shouldn't matter, but I'll check.